# multiple buttons working for just 1 modal - Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page where I show multiple items (unique items). This items are shown through PHP.

I am looking for a solution which allows me have just 1 modal, working for each item of the page shown by PHP.

I mean, I dont want to write the modal's code for each item of the page, if not, only one modal which works for all.

Of course, I have some variables and need use them in the modal.

Thank you.

Comment: You have to make Modals for every different Button. No way around that

Comment: are you sure **100%**? I thought I had seen something like this, but now can not find it.

Comment: Yes i am. Even if you use a call to a URL, you need to have a different Modal for every Button, because one Modal only calls one URL.